# How to broadcast/share a variable/property from a slave to the others?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script that is executed in distributed mode with 4 nodes. One of them is the controller and does not do any request and the other 3, as workers do the requests.

I can currently set one of the workers as a master worker, setting a property in the user.properties file for that specific worker. This "master" worker perform some requests that has to be done only once, so these requests can't be done by the other workers.

Now I have the need of extract some values from the response of these unique request and send this information to the other slaves.

Is it possible to do this?
How can data be sent form one worker to the other workers at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) plugin and populate it with data from the "master" worker using [`ADD` command](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#ADD) so once you do the setup of the pre-requisites all other workers including the master could access the generated data via [`READ` command](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ)

HTTP Simple Table server can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.

The communication between Controller and servers is very reduced:

- Controller send start / stop / shutdown commands to servers
- Servers send sample result to controller

That's it.

To communicate you'll need to use 3rd party tiers like Redis DB or similar means.